# about server-sent event timeout on mobile

Tags: javascript, java, timeout, server-sent-events

I use server-sent event to receive some event from server-side.here is the code:

```
var eventSource;
if(this.model.eventSource){
  eventSource = this.model.eventSource;
}else{
  var sseHandlerUrl = utils.config.baseUrl + "/video/ssehandler/" + lessonStore.id;
  var eventSource = new EventSource(sseHandlerUrl);
  this.model.eventSource = eventSource;
}
this.model.retryTime = 0;
eventSource.onopen = function(e) {
  console.log("onopen");
};

eventSource.addEventListener('error',function(event) {
  if (event.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
    self.closeVideo();
    closeEventSource(eventSource);
  } else {
    if(self.model.retryTime > 30){
      self.closeVideo();
      closeEventSource(eventSource);
      self.alertDialog("close", "network error!");
    }
    self.model.retryTime++;
  }
});
```

It works fine on PC,SSE conection will keepalive more then an hour.But on Andoird or iOS,the connection will disconnect in every 60 seconds.
  I appreciate if someone can tell me what happened.

Comment: ever found an alternative/fix to this?